# Creating an std::locale with an empty string ""

Tags: c++, locale, std

#### Question

Is constructing `std::locale` with an empty string to get the user-preferred native locale a part of the standard? If yes, could you point out a source which explicitly states that?

#### Problem description

Example from documentation of [`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) has this line:

```
std::wcout << "User-preferred locale setting is " << std::locale("").name().c_str()
```

Which hints that creating a locale with an empty string will return a user-preferred native locale. After quick googling, this [article](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/24-3.html) also mentions:

> The empty string tells setlocale to use the locale specified by the
>   user in the environment.

However, when looking at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) for `std::locale` constructors, there is no mentioning of a special case, when an empty string is provided.

Here's the quote:

> 3-4) Constructs a copy of the system locale with specified std_name
>   (such as "C", or "POSIX", or "en_US.UTF-8", or "English_US.1251"), if
>   such locale is supported by the operating system. The locale
>   constructed in this manner has a name.

Comment: [locale.cons]/6 has *Remarks: The set of valid string argument values is "C", "", and any implementation-defined values.*.  Still haven't found what using `""` should do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) says in **[locale.cons]**:

> ```
> explicit locale(const char* std_name);
> ```
>
> 4. *Effects:*
>      Constructs a locale using standard C locale names, e.g., `"POSIX"`. The resulting locale implements semantics defined to be associated with that name.
> 5. *Throws:*
>      `runtime_error` if the argument is not valid, or is null.
> 6. *Remarks:*
>      The set of valid string argument values is `"C"` , `""` , and any implementation-defined values.

This says `""` is a valid constructor argument, and arguments are standard C locale names.

Then in **[c.locale]** it explicitly refers to the standard C header `<locale.h>`.

Quoting from the C standard (C99), **7.11.1.1/3**:

> A value of `"C"` for `locale` specifies the minimal environment for C translation; a value of `""` for `locale` specifies the locale-specific native environment. Other implementation-defined strings may be passed as the second argument to `setlocale`.

I think this means the answer to your question is "yes": A name of `""` refers to the native locale.

Comment: Looks that way.  I was also able to find [facets.examples]/4 `cin.imbue(locale("")); // the user’s preferred locale`

Comment: Note that even though `""` is in the set of valid string arguments, I've seen exceptions thrown on `std::locale("")` (from a [plugin](https://github.com/divvun/libdivvun/issues/28) run under LibreOffice on Mac)